# Haskell, MongoDB, eval JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, haskell

I wrote a method to execute JavaScript code by using `eval` method in Haskell driver for MongoDB.

```
toolsDB_GenerateID :: Action IO Value
toolsDB_GenerateID = 
        eval (Javascript ([] :: [Field]) "var ret_id = db.counters.findAndModify({query: { _id: \'my_id\' },update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },new: true}); return {id:ret_id.seq};")::Action IO Value
```

It works!!!

I use that in the following:

```
inserData :: Action IO () 
inserData = do resultEval <-toolsDB_GenerateID 
               insert "test" ["id" =: resultEval]
               liftIO $ return ()
```

I just can not understand how I can get a real value from `Action IO Value`?

Like this:

```
Action IO Value -> Value
```

or

```
Action IO Value -> Int
```

How can I release that?

Comment: One does not simply remove a value from an `IO`... unless you're willing to use the black magic of `unsafePerformIO`... but that's generally frowned upon. You need [*monads*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)!

Comment: Taking the `Value` out of an `IO Value` makes as much sense as taking the cake out of a cake recipe. You need to use the cake recipe to put together a plan for making a meal, then hand the plan to the chef (named Run Time System or RTS) by giving it the name `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you ask, but chances are you do not need to. You can do the following, instead

```
foo :: Action IO SomeOtherType
foo = do value <- action -- where action :: Action IO SomeType
      -- here value :: SomeType can be used normally
      ...
      lastAction
```

with the only restriction that the `lastAction` has type `Action IO SomeOtherType`.

The thumb rule is, you can't extract a value from a monad forever, but you can extract it "temporarily" as long as you eventually produce another value inside the same monad. This is (arguably) what monads are all about, from a purely practical point of view.

I'd suggest you read some monad tutorial. [Monads in pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) is among the easiest, and one of my favourites. The one in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) is also good, and informative.